# XCode 4.2, Instruments seem to work different

Tags: ios, xcode

I know that Apple is constantly working on improving their software for developers. New Xcode 4.2 release also includes a new version of Instruments.

I can run it from Xcode as before (Product -> Profile). But it looks like things changed a bit, Leaks instrument is not working for me at all(doesn't depend on the application, it just shows nothing, even if a real memory leak is emerged), Allocations instrument is working as before, but it doesn't show any log in the Console application as it showed in older version.

In official Apple Developer's page I didn't find any guides, which could help me to solve the problem.

So my question - is there any good guides which can teach me how to use Instruments 4.2 properly? If someone knows why my problems could appear, I would be extremely glad to hear from you.

Artem

Comment: Not all memory loss is a leak, that is if there is still a reference to it.  Heapshot is really goos at finding those.

Comment: Thanks for the great answer, I will definetely try Heapshot. But question about guides for Instruments 4.2 is still relevant, because it is a bit difficult to switch to it after using older version.